# How to retrieve an ID with a FOR loop and set CSS rule?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I new on ASP.NET and I trying to do a web page based on VB code behind to set its behavior at frontend. And now I have list of asp Panel tags, each one has its own ID and it follows a numeric sequence. What I'm trying to do is to retrieve some of those IDs with a FOR loop to set them a CSS class. I thought it was gonna be something easy, but what a mistake!

Well, direct calls like this `myPanel7.CssClass = "green"` works. That's why naively I thought a simple code like this might works, but it does not.

```
For i=1 to x
  xID = “myPanel” & i.ToString()
  xID.CssClass = "green"
Next
```

So, I read some blogs and MS-docs and I understood that it’s necessary to create an object to inherit those properties, like ID and CSS. I tried this code and it works.

```
Dim xPanel As Panel
xID = "myPanel7"
xPanel = DirectCast(Page.FindControl(xID), Panel)
xPanel.CssClass = "green"
```

But when I tried to apply it on a FOR loop, it did not.

How can I solve this?, I need to get those IDs and apply one or another CSS rule.
Does anybody can, please, explain me what I'm doing wrong?
Why something like this does not work?

```
xID = "myPanel" & i.ToString()
```

Well, I leave you the structure of the code that I'm doing.
Thank you very much for your help.

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:Panel ID="Container" CssClass="frm" runat="server">
   <asp:Panel ID="Content" CssClass="txt" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="myPanel1" CssClass="white" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="myPanel2" CssClass="white" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="myPanel3" CssClass="white" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="myPanel4" CssClass="white" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        . . .
   </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

**Default.aspx.vb**

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Dim xID As String
      Dim xPanel As Panel

      For i As Integer = 1 to xVar
         xID = "myPanel" & i.ToString()
         xPanel = DirectCast(Page.FindControl(xID), Panel)
         xPanel.CssClass = "green"
      Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There must be something else (this should work) are you sure you're not resetting the Panels back to White on postback? Put in a breakpoint in the button click event and confirm its the last function to be called in the Page LifeCycle...

Comment: Make sure you set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for the project (and set it as thedefault for new projects). It'll point out some things that need to be corrected, which will probably lead you to why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are working with Master Pages.

So you can either use FindControl in a parent Container like `Container`

```
xPanel = DirectCast(Container.FindControl(xID), Panel)
```

Or use FindControl on the `ContentPlaceHolder` of the Page containing the controls and find that first

```
Dim cph = CType(Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"), ContentPlaceHolder)
```

And then in the loop

```
xPanel = DirectCast(cph.FindControl(xID), Panel)
```